# Connecting an ac-dc adapter and a battery in series

Tags: power-supply, dc, adapter, batteries

Can we connect a 12v adapter and a 12V battery in series to get a 24V output ?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/148352/is-it-safe-to-connect-battery-in-series-with-wall-adapter

Comment: You should not mix power sources like this.  You should not even mix different types of battery chemistries.

Comment: If you know what you are doing and given isolation on the 12 V adapter, yes, but beware of discharging your 12 V battery.

Comment: Yes, you can. Is it a good idea? No. Why you will dissipate power in the battery which could lead to the destruction of the battery. You need to match sources and loads when putting them in parallel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic answer is YES. But be aware. The 24 V obtained this way supplies energy from the wall adapter and the battery into your application. This causes the battery to discharge and the output voltage of the battery goes slowly down and so does the total voltage.

It therefore depends on your application if this option is feasable.

When discharging a battery you have to watch also the maximum discharge rate.
Example you have a battery of 12V 2 Ah - 1C and a wall adapter of 12 V 2A then you can safely connect an application that takes 24 V 2A. If however the battery specification indicates 12V 2Ah - 0,5C with the same wall adapter then you can only connect an application that takes 24 V 1A. otherwise the battery gets damaged.

In general it is like this. The weakest part in the supply chain determines the amount of current can be taken and fed to the application.